# Why can I not use for loops to remove one list from another?

Tags: python

Want to know why using 2 for loops wont work to delete one list from another

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    for item in b:
        for i in a:
            if item == i:
                a.remove(item)
```

a = [1,2,2]  b = [2]

Comment: You've got an error? or the result is not the same as your expected? Please give these information on your question

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's not recommended to remove an item from a list while iterating over it. Please provide more information about what your inputs and outputs are and why the current code isn't doing what you want. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove items from a list while iterating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207406/how-to-remove-items-from-a-list-while-iterating)

Comment: The result was not what I expected.  It should remove all values from a that are in b, so the result should be a = [1], instead I get a = [1,2]

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your function.

instead of

```py
def array_diff(a, b):
    for item in b:
        for i in a:
            if item == i:
                a.remove(item)
```

try:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    for item in b:
         for i in reversed(a):
             if item == i:
                 a.remove(i)
```

Answer (score 0):

As ggorlen said, it's not wise to remove items from a list while iterating through it. If you want just the items in `a` that are not in `b` consider using list comprehension and for extra efficiency a set. Consider:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    B = set(b)
    return [ x for x in a if x not in B ]
```

Using a set allows `x not in B` to be O(1) instead of O(n)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to loop and delete, please try this:

```
def array_diff(a, b):
    for item in b:
        for i in a[:]:
            if item == i:
                a.remove(item)
```

`a[:]` return a copy of a.

Answer (score 0):

you can just do a list comprehension

```
new = [c for c in a if c not in b]
```